# how to declare wrapped request in http post and net 6 framework

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

i'm working on a wcf application migration from net 4.8 to 6.
fundamental requirement it is essential that all clients continue to working without any changes. But for some methods, however, the behavior is different.

For example in net 4.8 we have this web method:

```
public ContractResult GetContract(int idContract)
{
   return a contract
}
```

clients call the method in post:

```
http://mywebserver/api/my.svc/GetContract
```

passing in body:

```
{"idContract":"245"}
```

this the net 6 version:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetContract")]
public ContractResult GetContract(int idContract)
{
  return a contract
}
```

the same call above returns statuscode 200 but the parameter contractId is always 0, the only way to make it working is to call in this way:

```
http://mywebserver/api/my.svc/GetContract?idContract=245
```

I tried to add the attribute:
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

but it seems not existing in net 6.

how to say to net 6 framework I want parameters serialized as json in body request?

Comment: There's no `.NET 6 framework`. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. And even in .NET Framework, `WebInvoke` was obsolete. It seems you have a WCF REST service, a short-lived technology that was replaced by Web API over 10 years ago.

Comment: To bind parameters to the body use the [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) attribute. The various options are explained in [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#model-binding-simple-and-complex-types) and are essentially a superset of Web API bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the code to look like this:

```
public class contractId
{
   public int idContract { get; set; }
}




[HttpPost]
[Route("GetContract")]
public ContractResult GetContract([FromBody]contractId idContract)
{
 if(idContract.idContract==245)
  return a contract
}
```

Then send the json

```
{"idContract":245}
```

I think the problem is model binding. By default, you are using **[FromQuery]**, you need to use **[FromBody]**.

Comment: It works even without FromBody. Maybe FromQuery Is the default only on base types